# Weekly Profit & Loss Statement From Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to make a weekly P&L report but haven't had any success yet. I wanted to know whether this was achievable (without having to change financial periods to weekly). The furthest I am is creating a GI (and report) with GLTran then filtering by the dates. But I then will have to categorize everything as per a financial statement which might not be the ideal solution.

Thanks
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design this by using advanced report designer.  You may have to create few additional columns in the chart of accounts to hold headings for different levels.

Comment: hi @dick smith, this will determine the right order (sales, less cogs etc etc) I agree but would there be anyway to for example get gross profit out of it? because I can't get a proper value at that particular point and then continue with expenses.

Comment: Made it happen using some grouping and sorting :)